# who can I use the search box to access JSON data and display it on another page?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have an array of JSON data like this:

```
var trackListings = [{
    "tName": "Breathe",
        "duration": 2.5
}, {
    "tName": "On The Run",
        "duration": 2
}, {
    "tName": "Time",
        "duration": 6
}, {
    "tName": "The Great Gig In the Sky",
        "duration": 5
}, ];
```

I have another page, just a simple HTML page contains search box and a search button. what I want to do is, from the search box page, as I type the track name I want to search, I want to access all the tName data in the above JSON array and display it on the other page, preferably in table form.

what should I write at the button form & search input text form in the search box page? or should I just leave the forms plainly, like this?

```
<form class="form-search" action="window.open('dwChart.html')" method="get">
<input id="srch" type="search" class="input-medium search-query">
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="searchAction()">
```

about the JSON array..where should I put the code block? in the search box page or in the result page? how can I access the JSON data? using JQuery or plainly use JavaScript?

I really need to sort this thing out as soon as possible..

Comment: you need a ajax request to a dynamic page, written in php that search for a keywoard eg. in a db and returns the results as json, or you use twitters bootstraps typeahead (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead)

Answer (score 0):

You should check out JQuery, JQueryUI and the JQuery [autocomplete widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DPlugins%2FAutocomplete%2Fsearch%26redirect%3Dno#entry-examples)

To use that, you'll need to embed the jquery framework javascript and CSS into the `<head>` of your page:

```
<head>
...
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
<script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js?ver=3.4.1"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
...
</head>
```

Then you can add some javascript/jquery code to instantiate an autocomplete widget on your search box. You'll need to add this code inside a `<script>` block below where you included the JQuery framework.

If your list of JSON items is fairly short, you can just embed it right into the javascript code that invokes the autocomplete widget:

```
$( "#srch" ).autocomplete({
  source: [ "Breathe", "On the Run", "Time", "The Great Gig In The Sky"]
});
```

Otherwise, you can use a callback function to lookup the item from a separate object on the page, or from a separate file.